# When to use skills, when to use stats?

Tags: skills, burning-wheel

So if I understand BW correctly most of the rolls in this games that determine a resolution to conflict use **Skills** (sword, brawling, wises etc.) And according to the book if you don't have a given skill you use **Beginner's Luck**. Is there any instance where you use your **Stats** (Power, Will, etc.)?

Would assuming that something less specific, like pushing a giant stone, would use a **Stat** (like Power), be correct? Or do I have to find the closest **Skill** in the list that would apply and if a player doesn't have it then roll **Beginner's Luck**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've concluded, you test Stats when you're doing simple things where a Skill doesn't apply.

You'll test these Stats the most frequently:

- Power to push past someone or perform feats of strength.
- Speed to race or outrun someone. It's also rolled in Fight and Range and Cover.
- Perception to notice things or details—but watch out for overlaps with the Observation skill.

You'll usually only test Will directly when trying to Avoid the Topic in a Duel of Wits.  Unless you're a sorcerer testing for Tax, you're probably not rolling Forte all that often, either.  I've never tested Agility, although I could imagine a “Take the pebble from my hand, grasshopper” situation.

Comment: If you are in a Beginner's Luck situation, but the test is difficult or challenging, you are testing the relevant stat. This is one way to generate tests for stats that are otherwise rarely tested. E.g. Beginner's Luck Drinking (versus test between drinkers) can generate Forte tests.